# A computed which "sleeps" until some initialization completes

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a complex viewmodel, which holds several observable properties, arrays, etc. I have a computed observable which has several dependencies. The logic inside the computed mustn't be executed at definition time, but only after the model is fully initialized.

Example:

Image a form where users can select one of more continents, countries or cities. Each time some continents get selected, the list of countries should contain only those which are located on the selected continents, and the same for cities, etc.

For optimizing HTTP traffic, the initial lists are populated as part of the page, so that no initial JSON request is needed.

```
var viewModel = function(data) {
  this.Continents = ko.observableArray(data.Continents);
  this.Countries = ko.observableArray(data.Countries);
  this.Cities = ko.observableArray(data.Cities);

  this.SelectedContinents = ko.observableArray(data.SelectedContinents);
  this.SelectedCountries = ko.observableArray(data.SelectedCountries);
  this.SelectedCities = ko.observableArray(data.SelectedCities);

  this.LoadFromServer = function() {
    $.post({
      url: '/reloadLists',
      data: { continents: this.SelectedContinents(), countries: this.SelectedCountries(), cities: this.SelectedCities() },
      success: function(result) {
        this.Continents(result.Continents);     
        this.Countries(result.Countries);
        this.Cities(result.Cities);
      } 
    });
  };

  ko.computed(function() {
    this.LoadFromServer();
  }, this);

}

...

var data = ... // initial data rendered on server-side 
var model = new viewModel(data);
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

With this approach, the problem is that the LoadFromServer logic gets executed also at the model initialization when the computed initially executes the rad function. This way there is a redundant round-trip, because the initial lists are already in the model.

The only solution I can think of right now is to introduce a flag to block the concrete logic until it's needed. This flag shouldn't be an observable because then when I set it to true at the end of the constructor, the computed will get re-evaluated, and the redundant round-trip goes again. However, if the flag is not an observable, then I have to make sure that the dependencies are caught at initialization time, so that it can react to changes afterwards. Putting all this together, the currenct result looks something like this.

```
var viewModel = function(data) {

  var initialized = false;

  this.Continents = ko.observableArray(data.Continents);
  this.Countries = ko.observableArray(data.Countries);
  this.Cities = ko.observableArray(data.Cities);

  this.SelectedContinents = ko.observableArray(data.SelectedContinents);
  this.SelectedCountries = ko.observableArray(data.SelectedCountries);
  this.SelectedCities = ko.observableArray(data.SelectedCities);

  this.LoadFromServer = function() {
    $.post({
      url: '/reloadLists',
      data: { continents: this.SelectedContinents(), countries: this.SelectedCountries(), cities: this.SelectedCities() },
      success: function(result) {
        this.Continents(result.Continents);     
        this.Countries(result.Countries);
        this.Cities(result.Cities);
      } 
    });
  };

  ko.computed(function() {
    var catchDependencies = [this.SelectedContinents(), this.SelectedCountries(), this.SelectedCities()];
    if (!initialized) return;
    this.LoadFromServer();
  }, this);  

  initialized = true;
}
```

This is technically a good solution but I don't quite like it because it has some smell for me.

Is there any nicer solution for these scenarios? Or I just shouldn't try to optimize things and let the initial AJAX load instead of the server-side initialo data rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, a computed that doesn't return a value is a code smell, because it's a tool with one purpose that you're using as a sort of multi-subscribe. It would be clearer to set up explicit subscriptions:

```
  this.SelectedContinents.subscribe(this.LoadFromServer);
  this.SelectedCountries.subscribe(this.LoadFromServer);
  this.SelectedCities.subscribe(this.LoadFromServer);
```

It is not clear to me whether `LoadFromServer` needs to be externally visible; you could do it as a private function.

Comment: Yes, to be honest I agree, but lots of people are using them this way and it's quite common scneario. Also, subscribing to array changes has a quite ugly syntax, and if I have 5-6 dependent arrays, then it produces a lot of code. However I'm gonna think about some helper method and with that it could be really cleaner.

Comment: You can loop over the variables if you have so many that the redundant code is bothersome. You could also write a helper function called `multiSubscribe` that does the looping. It doesn't require more code than the computed kludge.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was thinking about explicit subscriptions before, but chose the - first glance - easier way. But now you convinced me, thank you.

Comment: Although it's more verbose, verbosity is not bad at all: this is the option that makes it more clear the intention of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
ko.computed(function() {
  if(ko.computedContext.isInitial()) return;
  this.LoadFromServer();
}, this);
```

Read more [Here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-reference.html#using-the-computed-context).

Comment: Thank you, ah, I was actually looking for something like this, but couldn't find at first glance. However, I would still need the dummy dependency array at the beginning, is it right?

Comment: See the `deferEvaluation` option http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-reference.html.

Comment: I know about deferEvaluation option, but the computed is an "implicit" one. I mean it is not assigned to a member, and never gets called because it's task is to maintain the object state, not to compute some kind of value.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási no you don't need that dependency array. `ko` will do it for you.

Comment: @Dandy I got a bit confused and put together a test here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hsakn8qs/). As you can see, if I comment out line 7 (the dummy dependency array), the test will not work. Knockout dependency detenction detects dependencies by reaching them at each evaluation of a computed. Due to checkiong isInitial at the very beginning) it won't detect any dependency and the computed will be a living-dead. If you correct your answer I'll accept it though because you pointed out the idea.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási the problem is the `return;` statment. it just return from function and dont track the later dependencies. So dont return and move your logic inside the `isInitial` condition block. Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hsakn8qs/2/)

Comment: Okay but in my example the call to LoadFromServer was implicitly referenced the dependent observable arrays. I don't need to run special code when it's the initial run or it isn't. I needed the complete computed body logic to be skipped on initial run. Hope you understand.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási You would call the computed where you are now setting `initialized` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm not sure if this is the best way but it works.

So my approach is, I have created a flag called `isComplete` and if this is true then show computed value else show default value. This is for HTML so that bindings does not fail.

Also I have added a button  where I'm registering computed value. it can also do it on subscribe of certain value.

```js
var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = ko.observable(first);
    self.lastName = ko.observable(last);
  self.isComplete = ko.observable(false);
  
    // Computed registered section
    self.registerComputed = function(){
        if(!self.hasOwnProperty("fullName")){
            self.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
                return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
            }, this);
        }
        self.isComplete(true);
    }
};
 
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth"));
```

```css
body { font-family: arial; font-size: 14px; }
.liveExample { padding: 1em; background-color: #EEEEDD; border: 1px solid #CCC; max-width: 655px; }
.liveExample input { font-family: Arial; }
.liveExample b { font-weight: bold; }
.liveExample p { margin-top: 0.9em; margin-bottom: 0.9em; }
.liveExample select[multiple] { width: 100%; height: 8em; }
.liveExample h2 { margin-top: 0.4em; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class='liveExample'>   
    <p>First name: <input data-bind='value: firstName' /></p> 
    <p>Last name: <input data-bind='value: lastName' /></p> 
    <h2>Hello, <span data-bind='text: isComplete()?fullName():""'> </span>!</h2>  
    <button data-bind="click:registerComputed, text:'Register Full Name'"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I think it's a different problem from what I've posted about. Probably you misunderstood my question, sorry if it wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is the [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-reference.html) `deferEvaluation` option:

> Optional. If this option is true, then the value of the computed observable will not be evaluated until something actually attempts to access its value or manually subscribes to it. By default, a computed observable has its value determined immediately during creation.

Te idea is setting this option, and manually accessing the observable when the initialization has finished, so that it "becomes active". Of course, you have to store it in a "private" variable to be able to access it.

Please, see also this: [Lazy Loading an Observable in KnockoutJS](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/06/lazy-loading-observable-in-knockoutjs.html)

Comment: Thank you, but this is another scenario. Here my computed is not exposed to any property, and not calculating some result value, but only maintaining the object state. Defering the evaluation is great when one has a computed which actually does some calculations and returns a value.

Comment: The idea is to activate the computed observable by manually accessing it in the same place that you're now setting initialized to true. If this has nothing to do with what you need, then I didn't understand the problem. If so, let me know, and I'll delete the answer. Tnank you!

Comment: One key is that I don't want to activate them at that point. If I wanted I could make the initialized variable an obsevable. So what I wanted is just skip the initial, BUT gather the dependencies so that on next run the computed will execute normally.